# boto3 iam client: get policy by name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get a policy from boto3 client but there is no method to do so using policy name. By wrapping the create_policy method in a try-except block i can check whether a policy exists or not. Is there any way to get a policy-arn by name using boto3 except for listing all policies and iterating over it.

Answer (score 6):

The ARN should be deterministic given the prefix (if any, and the name).

```
iam = session.client('iam')
sts = session.client('sts')

# Slow and costly if you have many pages
paginator = iam.get_paginator('list_policies')
all_policies = [policy for page in paginator.paginate() for policy in page['Policies']]
[policy_1] = [p for p in all_policies if p['PolicyName'] == policy_name]

# Fast and direct
account_id = sts.get_caller_identity()['Account']
policy_arn = f'arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:policy/{policy_name}'
policy_2 = iam.get_policy(PolicyArn=policy_arn)['Policy']

# They're equal except with the direct method you'll also get description field
all(policy_1[k] == policy_2[k] for k in policy_1.keys() & policy_2.keys())
```

Comment: This will not work for AWS-managed policies since they do not have an account number in the ARN. For example, the much-loved `AdministratorAccess` policy has the following ARN: `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess`. It does, however work for any customer-managed policies, but should be well guarded if used.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over the policies to get policy names. I am not aware of a get-policy type api that uses policy names only policy ARNs.

Is there a reason that you do not want to get a list of policies? Other than to not download the list.

Comment: The reason is only to not download the list. When the local managed policy count is really large it may take several iterations to get all policies which sort of is inefficient for my use-case.